# .Maui C# VS unable to find packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

i recently started with C-Sharp and VS
I'm creating a MAUI app for a school project
On my Laptop the App works, but on my PC i get errors for the same Code.
I have exactly the same libraries and SDKs on both machines
and the App is a Maui preset. I didn't change any code

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Fragment. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Google.Android.Material. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Google.Crypto.Tink.Android. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Common. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Glide. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1   
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   ThatsApp3   C:\Users\sebas\CloudDrive\Meine Dateien\001 Dev\C#\iet-322 Frontend\ThatsApp\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3\ThatsApp3.csproj   1
```

after launching maui-check (thanks to Robert Harvey and PMF) and auto-fix it i recieve this anwser

```
> .NET SDK - Workloads (6.0.301) Checkup...
  - android (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Android.Manifest-6.0.300 : 32.0.440) installed.
  - ios (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.iOS.Manifest-6.0.300 : 16.1.229) installed.
  - maccatalyst (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.MacCatalyst.Manifest-6.0.400 : 16.1.229) installed.
  - tvos (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.tvOS.Manifest-6.0.400 : 16.1.229) installed.
  - macos (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.macOS.Manifest-6.0.400 : 13.0.784) installed.
  - maui (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Maui.Manifest-6.0.300 : 6.0.419) installed.
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

- Congratulations, everything looks great!
```

but it is still not working.

Comment: Run [maui-check](https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check) and do what it says.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i can't install the maui-check via console. so something is really wrong.
C:\Users\sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\9fc31e9d-cf5a-45d1-9329-7d5d51e4ef21\restore.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package redth.net.maui.check. No packages exist with this id in source(s):

Comment: Do you have a `Nuget.config` in your repository?

Comment: i have this file under %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

Comment: btw. i checked the difference of the file compared to my laptop. on the laptop there was one line more
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
so i added it and it works now. thanks. really lovely

Comment: at which moment did i miss having the possibilty to add this line to the config file?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.....
Developer mode was desactivated on my PC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).